# Getting unexpected semicolon error when using PlugNPay PHP Library

Tags: php, authorization, credit-card

When I try to use the [third-party PHP library for Plug N Pay](http://code.google.com/p/plugnpay-php/downloads/list) (a credit card authorization library), I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /authtest/PnP.php on line 391
```

Line 391 reads:

```
    $http_query = str_replace("&amp;", "&", (http_build_query( $post_args ) );
```

Removing this line runs the script but obviously returns another error as $http_query is not set. I've replaced the default user/pass with my specific PnP user/pass, for what it's worth.

Googling turns up not much, and this server is running PHP5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are missing a closing `)` before the `;`  and/or have an unnecessary `(`,
depending on how you look at it.

```
$http_query = str_replace("&amp;", "&", (http_build_query( $post_args ) );
```

should be

```
$http_query = str_replace("&amp;", "&", (http_build_query( $post_args ) ) );
```

or even better

```
$http_query = str_replace("&amp;", "&", http_build_query( $post_args ) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Stupid question driving me nuts. I'll be sure to submit a patch and link back to your contribution!